# Can't drop row from dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

so I have a data set that i work in Jupyter Notebook. Its like this:

|  | Riding | Filipino Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Eglinton-Lawrence | 12421.750 |
| 1 | York Centre | 17639.200 |
| 2 | Don Valley East | 7267.260 |
| 3 | Scarborough Centre | 14468.950 |
| 4 | Scarborough Southwest | 10288.025 |
| 5 | Scarborough-Rouge Park | 9434.385 |
| 6 | Scarborough-Guildwood | 8594.775 |

Every time I've tried to drop the Row (0) Zero, it will return with, `KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'`.

To drop the row, I use this following

```
pop_filipino2_DF_with_percent.drop([0], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I tried to create a new dataframe, `df_filipino2_clean = pop_filipino2_DF_with_percent.drop([0],axis=1,inplace=True)`, but it also return with --> `KeyError: '[0] not found in axis'`.

The question is, how to drop the first row (0)?

Comment: Why are you using `axis=1` when you want to drop _row_? Just try `df.drop(0)`

Comment: `pop_filipino2_DF_with_percent.drop(0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because you're attempting to drop a column. The correct way to do it is:

```py
pop_filipino2_DF_with_percent.drop([0], inplace=True)
```